# convert list to bytestring for Google pub/sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am running into an issue while publishing messages to google cloud pub/sub service from a python client.

I have rest based public API which returns JSON data. The returned data is in dictionary form within in a list.

I have extracted the values from the dictionary into a list and using bytes() to convert to the bytestring however it is still throwing the exception below.

`['EB', 'Pulaski', '2018-03-06 21:50:18.0', '0.5', '41.7930671862', '41.793140551', '-87.7136071496', 'W', 'Central Park', '-1', '1', '-87.7231602513', '55th']`

```
response = requests.get("https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/8v9j-bter.json")
traffic = response.json()


result_list = []
for d in traffic:
  result_list.append([v for k, v in d.items()])

for x in result_list:
  print(x)
  publisher.publish(topic_path, data = bytes(x))
```

Comment: What exception?

Comment: pub/sub must be sent as a bytestring

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should use x.encode('utf-8') instead of bytes(x) to convert to bytestring, according to the Python sample here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish-messages-to-a-topic